Device tree patching in Yocto for stm32mp157d
I'm currently learning how to create a device tree patch for a stm32mp157d-dk1 board with Yocto version Mickledore. I've been following along a Digikey tutorial with small deviance from differing Yocto versions, linked here.
When I followed the steps in patching, adding busybox for i2cdetect, and finally running bitbake custom-image, I get this error:
ERROR: Task (/home/frame/repos/yocto/meta-st-stm32mp/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-stm32mp_6.1.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

This is the file structure of my custom layer recipes-kernel where I've placed the .bbappend and .patch files
── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        ├── linux-stm32mp1
        │   └── 0001-add-i2c5-userspace-dts.patch
        │  
        └── linux-stm32mp_%.bbappend

Additionally here is the code block inside:
0001-add-i2c5-userspace-dts.patch
diff --git a/stm32mp157d-dk1.dts.orig b/stm32mp157d-dk1.dts
index 4bc9fc8..1285023 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp157d-dk1.dts
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32mp157d-dk1.dts
@@ -25,3 +25,13 @@
                stdout-path = "serial0:115200n8";
        };
 };
+
+&i2c5 {
+       pinctrl=names = "default", "sleep";
+       pinctrl-0 = <&i2c5_pins_a>;
+       pinctrl-1 = <&i2c5_sleep_pins_a>;
+       i2c-scl-rising-time-ns = <185>;
+       i2c-scl-falling-time-ns = <20>;
+       clock-frequency = <100000>;
+       status = "okay";
+};

linux-stm32mp_%.bbappend
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-add-i2c5-userspace-dts.patch"

bitbake custom-image compiles correctly if I remove the modifications and busybox, but I'm not quite sure where the error lies.

You didn't posted the whole error message, so can't be tell anything there. From the directory structure, I think you need "${THISDIR}:linux-stm32mp1" or   "${THISDIR}:files" in FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend.

I'm an idiot, I read the log files and it was a syntax error inside 0001-add-i2c5-userspace-dts.patch, specifically this line:
 pinctrl=names = "default", "sleep";

The assignment variable should've been pinctrl-names.
